# MySQL: when to write a views or a stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, view

I would like to create a table that calculates the user_ranks based on conditions present in several other tables.

Am I right in thinking that both views and stored procedures produce a virtual table? I understand that a view is 'continually updated' as the data changes whereas a stored procedure is only updated when externally executed. Once a stored procedure is run a table will be created in the database and its data will persist until is run again. Is that right?

I need to update the user_ranks only once a week and for that reason, I am thinking of using a stored procedure that my app will call once a week. I would like to know if this approach is correct?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: With specific regard to MySQL, a rule of thumb that works for me for when to create views is NEVER. For procedures, the rule I use is 'only when the problem is truly procedural'.

Comment: The use of a Stored Proceedure will create a transient resultset just like doing a SELECT as will a view